# Ruby on Rails - How to manage layouts in admin interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very simple site setup using [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) and a single table called Pages.

I would like the ability to select different layouts in the admin when creating and updating Pages. What I envisioned is a drop down on the Pages form that allowed me to select a layout/template.

The only thing I know about layouts is you are required to add them to /views/layouts/ and specify the layout at the top of the controller. I need a way to manage layouts on a per Page basis inside the app itself.

Is that even possible? If so, can you explain on a high level how that might be done so I can have a starting point?

**edit**

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have files in `views/layouts` called something like one_column.html.erb, two_column.html.erb, etc., and an attribute called `layout` on you page model, you could just do:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  render :action => "show", :layout => @page.layout
end
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think so, yeah. You must have been answering at the same time I added nearly the same follow up question to karmajunkie's answer. Eventually I'd like to manage the contents of the layouts in the admin also, but for now I'm fine with creating a few pre-defined layouts (one_column.html.erb, two_column.html.erb) and then just selecting them via the attribute drop down. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I am glad it helps.  P.S. - If it's your answer please mark it. :-)

Comment: Done! Hey by the way, do you think this is a dumb idea? I'm a total noob so I don't know if this goes against convention. I basically want to have diff layouts for diff pages.

Comment: I don't think so because I've done something similar. :-) There implementation here is obviously quite simple, but simple is okay if it meets your needs.  If you need something more complex in the future than you can add more functionality to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily change the layout at render by supplying the :layout key like so:

```
def some_action
   #... stuff
   render "some_action", :layout => "custom_layout"
end
```

You can also set layout to a symbol in the controller definition, and the controller will run the associated method to decide what layout to choose

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout :decide_layout

  private
    def decide_layout
       some_boolean ? "layout1" : "layout2"
    end
end
```

You can also replace the symbol with a proc if you don't want the method located away from the usage.  Finally, you can also call #layout in an action itself.